# Err #1006 value is not a function in str.replace()

Tags: actionscript-3, string, replace

I'm doing a small parsing of a web-page.
I have a piece of code:

```
var names:Array = pageText.match(namePattern);
for (i=0; names.length>i; i++)
{
    if (names[i].search("show") != -1)
    {
       names[i] = names[i].slice(names[i].search(additionalNamePattern) + 2,-4);
    }
    trace((names[i].toString()==names[i] ? 'true': 'false'),typeof names[i], ': ', names[i]);
    //Gives: true string :  <span class="title">Dancing Queen </span><span class="

    trace(typeof names[i].replace , ': ',names[i].replace);
    //Gives: function :  function Function() {}

    if (names[i])
    {
        trace(names[i].replaсe("a","b")); 
        //Gives Error TypeError: Error #1006: value is not a function.
    }
```

The question is, obviously, why is it raising the error. I've already tried

`"abc".replace("b", "c")`

and it works.

`trace(typeof "abc".replace , ': ',"abc".replace);`

gives

`function :  function Function() {}`

Comment: Type your variables and you won't have to hunt mystery bugs like this.

Comment: That is bizarre.. Somebody should write a tool/something to detect out-of-locale characters in programs and other text documents. Reminds me of an old PayPal phishing attack that featured a domain name registered with Russian letter 'a'

Comment: I thought about that too. The tool should think about comments and constant strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your answers!

The solution is strange and funny. I had to reprint the word `replace` and it began compiling correctly. I've just changed `replaсe` to `replace`.

After it I've checked it and ststed, that there are 2 different letters in these words. The last two in the first word are Russian letters.

Comment: So how did those characters get there in the first place? Is this copied and pasted from somewhere else?

Comment: I think I put them myself, when switched from jabber:)

Answer (score 1):

Just curious, but what happens if you do the following:

```
//place this at the top:
import flash.utils.getQualifiedClassName;

// this line will make sure that everything is a String (req's Flash 10.x)
var names:Vector.<String> = Vector.<String>(pageText.match(namePattern));

trace(getQualifiedClassName(names[i]))
if (names[i])
{
     trace(String(names[i]).replaсe("a","b")); 
}
```

I know, those *shouldn't matter*, but AS3 has some quirks. I have seen some similar behavior in AS2 which was fixed by those though, I'm wondering if AS3 won't be the same.

Comment: Curiouser and curiouser:)
This leaded to noncompilation with `1061: Call to a possibly undefined method replaсe through a reference with static type String.`

Answer (score 1):

just a reminder:  getting the 'typeof' of String.replace will return 'function' because that's what it is... you'll need to use the () in order to execute the function and therefore get the returned result.

replace() = "run this function"

replace  =  name of the function itself.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I was just making sure, that I haven't redefined it with any strange variable.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing.

```
for (i=0; names.length>i; i++){
to 
for each( var name:String in names ){
```

and then change all the references to

```
names[i].
change to 
name.
```

Since this will type cast name to String it will help you find the issue.

I do have to admit though that your code is pretty sloppy.
Maybe if you tell us what you are trying to achieve we do it cleaner.

Comment: It has changed the error number to `1061: Call to a possibly undefined method replaсe through a reference with static type String`

Really, I'm trying to parse a web page for track names and clear them from `<span>` tag. I was trying to show minimum code, which leads to the error, with maximum debugging:)

Comment: is it equal in these cases:
`names[i]=names[i].join("a")`
and
`name=name.join("a")`

Comment: well the code you posted in your comment has nothing to do with the error you posted above it. But judging from the code I see an issue. if going off my code "name" is typed as a String and in your code here you are doing name.join('a') that is an array function which will give you an error undefined method.

Comment: After looking at a comment below I copied and pasted String(names[0] ).replaсe("a","b") and I was getting the issue also as it turns out the "c" in the word replace is not a "c" If you retype the word replace instead of copy and paste your undefined method replace error will go away

Comment: Interesting how copy and pasting works oh looks like you already found it